# Order by won't work in my sqlite3 statement

Tags: select, sqlite, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have an sqlite3 statement that generates a column from creating a union from more than one table.

I then try to order the column in ascending order. It is a numeric column and defined as such.

It orders everything just fine, except for one number that it puts in the beginning and not in order, and orders the rest just fine. Like so:

```
27
10
13
26
28
29
29
30
35
```

Which makes me wonder if somehow that number (27 above) somehow isn't numeric? but a char maybe?

I tried solving this using:

```
Order by column*1
Order by UPPER(column)
Order by CAST(column as int) 
order by ABS(column)
order by column collate BINARY
order by column collate NOCASE
order by column collate RTRIM
```

Everything I could find to make it a natural sort and convert to numbers.

All the above either returned syntax errors or didn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT typeof(MyColumn) FROM ...`?

Comment: @CL. you helped me fix it! Turns out all the numbers were text because the columns included 'NaN' values, except for one which returned real values since all numbers were actually present. So it was a real value vs a text value situation. For future reference, how would this be solved, if not with collate?

Comment: Ensure that the values have the correct type to begin with; converting them in every query afterwards is too much hassle.